# Class inheritance question in magento (google analytics)

Tags: class, inheritance

In a custom module I'm inserting universal analytics so I have to change a few functions from `Ga.php` file

In `Ga.php` there is:

```
class Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
//google analytics functions
}
```

If I do like this:

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Universalanalytics extends Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga{ 
//a couple of functions that I change from Ga.php
}
```

it doesn't work.

But if I do like this:

```
class Custom_Module_Block_Universalanalytics extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{  
//all functions from Ga.php plus the ones that I change
}
```

it does work.

So my question is why wouldn't it work if I extend the `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga` class which already has all the functions?

Update: Here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Custom_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <universalanalytics>
                <class>Custom_Module_Block</class>
            </universalanalytics>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <universalanalytics>
                <class>Custom_Module_Helper</class>
            </universalanalytics>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <universalanalytics>
                <class>Custom_Module_Model</class>
            </universalanalytics>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <universalanalytics_order_success>
                        <class>universalanalytics/observer</class>
                        <method>setUniversalanalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView</method>
                    </universalanalytics_order_success>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <universalanalytics_order_success>
                        <class>universalanalytics/observer</class>
                        <method>setUniversalanalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageView</method>
                    </universalanalytics_order_success>
                </observers>
            </checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
        </events>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <universalanalytics>
                    <file>universalanalytics.xml</file>
                </universalanalytics>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Thanks!

Update: Folowing the comments, indeedthe issue is with this function:

```
protected function _toHtml(){
    if (!Mage::helper('universalanalytics')->isUniversalanalyticsAvailable()) {
        return '';
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

`Mage::helper('universalanalytics')->isUniversalanalyticsAvailable()` is returning true, but, as I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179732/overwritten-block-appears-in-addition-to-module-overwrite `return parent::_toHtml();` will return the google classic analytics object.

Comment: please show your  Custom_Module module config.xml code?

Comment: @AmitBera done that

Comment: Are you sure this `Mage::helper('googleanalytics')->isGoogleAnalyticsAvailable())` is returning `true`? If not, the `toHtml` function will return an empty string.

Comment: how you have call Custom_Module_Block_Universalanalytics file in your code?

Comment: @Mayers I've created `Mage::helper('universalanalytics')->isUniversalanalyticsAvailable()` which is returning true. I want the client to be able to control it from the admin.

Comment: @Claudiu Sorry what I meant is, in the class that you extend, there is a `_toHtml` function that will return an empty string is `isGoogleAnalyticsAvailable` returns false. And since your class extends this one, it inherits this function (unless you rewrite it)

Comment: @Mayers indeed that is the issue. thanks for help. It will be an issue to rewrite it as I want both classic and universal on the same page?

Comment: It will be okay. Based on the config.xml, you just created a new class that extend the core class, you didn't rewrite the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class that you extend, there is a `_toHtml` function that will return an empty string is `isGoogleAnalyticsAvailable()` returns `false`. And since your class extends this one, it inherits this function (unless you rewrite it)